# Jpanel does not display what it supposes to

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have created a class that extends JPanel using eclipse, now i added this class to netbeans through creating a new JFrame and dragging this class to the Jframe using the Netbeans designer. now at run time, the Camera stream do not show on the jpanel despite the same code was runnning in eclipse.

is there any attribute i ahve to modify its value in the netbeans designer to get the jpanel working?

**Code**:

```
private static class CamThreadRun implements  Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        camStream();
    }
}

private static void camStream() {
        while(vidCap.grab()) {
            grappedMat = new Mat();
            vidCap.retrieve(grappedMat);

            if (!grappedMat.empty()) {
                BufferedImage buffImg = mat2BufferedImage(grappedMat);

                if (buffImg != null) {
                    facePanel.setFace(buffImg);
                    facePanel.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember exactly but Netbeans creates some kind of .form file that doesn't get recognised in eclipse. It's best to design it yourself with the code as it will work on both IDEs instead of using Netbeans GUI designer which works best for Netbeans.